# c# client.GetPreSignedURL in .net aws sdks using HMACSHA256 instead of AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk-net

the url generated from the method is different when compared with presigned url from aws console

from c# method
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxx&Expires=1642609317&Signature=xxxxx

**c# link not working**

from AWS Console:

https://bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/key?response-content-disposition=inline&X-Amz-Security-Token=xxx&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220119T154450Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Credential=xxxxxx&X-Amz-Signature=xxxxxxxxx

package versions using

```
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.7.6" />
<PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.7.14" />
```

in the  package available algorithms

```
namespace Amazon.Runtime
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The valid hashing algorithm supported by the sdk for request signing.
    public enum SigningAlgorithm
    {
        HmacSHA1 = 0,
        HmacSHA256 = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  The C# SDK is using AWS4-HMAC-SHA256, is that a problem?

Comment: @AnonCoward, I am trying to generate a presigned url from C# code, when accessed it, showing error to use this AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 for signature. with the latest AWS sdk I couldn't find that algorithm. Then I tried to generate from console, the link generated is different when compared with SDK. I would like to create presigned link from AWS SDK that works

Comment: You want to use "HmacSHA256" then.

Comment: @Vman did you figure it out?  I have a similar issue - C# client, 2 environments, same code.  One generates a AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 and works, the other does not and fails

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker saw this issue 4 years ago only in us-east-1 on another project and put in the fix below.  I plan to do the same.

```
Amazon.AWS.ConfigS3.UserSignatureVersion4 = true;
```